# CSV as text node of an XML element

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb, xml-serialization

What are the pros and cons of putting CSV formatted data inside an xml element?

I must serialize objects in java with a matrix data field to xml. I abandoned the idea of using data binding with Jaxb; generics and collections containing collections are too much of a pain to deal with.

I thought of a simple schema for my matrix, but since I will also have to implement serialization of matrices to CSV, why not just dump a CSV string as a text node in an element? It would also make files a bit smaller.

Can you think of arguments against this idea?

Should I add something like a csv mimetype to this element?

EDIT: Here's the solution I opted for. It uses Super-CSV. The enum is needed because the generic type is erased at runtime. The main xml file will reference the csv files.

```
static public enum SerializableType{INTEGER,DOUBLE,...};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Matrix<T> fromCSV(InputStream in, CsvPreference pref, SerializableType t)
{

    Matrix<T> o = new Matrix<T>();
    // Super-csv class
    CsvListReader csv_reader = new CsvListReader(new InputStreamReader(in), pref);

    Integer n = null;
    try {
        List<String> l = csv_reader.read(); 
        n = l.size(); o.n = n;

        int i=0;

        while(l!=null)
        {
            o.appendRow();
            T val;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                switch(t)
                {
                case INTEGER:
                    val = (T)Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(l.get(j)));
                    break;
                case DOUBLE:
                    val = (T)Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(l.get(j)));
                    break;
                case <...>

                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                o.set(i,j, val);
            }
            i++;

            l = csv_reader.read();
        }

        csv_reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return o;
}


public static<T> void toCSV(Matrix<T> m, CsvListWriter csv_writer, SerializableType t)
{

    try {

        for(int i=0;i<m.rowCount();i++)
        {
            ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int j=0;j<m.columnCount();j++)
            {
                if(m.get(i,j)==null)
                {
                    l.add(null);
                }
                else{
                    switch(t)
                    {
                    case INTEGER:
                        l.add(Integer.toString((Integer)m.get(i,j)));
                        break;
                    case DOUBLE:
                        l.add(Double.toString((Double)m.get(i,j)));
                        break;
                    case 
                        <...>

                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    };
                }
            }

            csv_writer.write(l);
        }

        csv_writer.flush();
        csv_writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading bits of some terse w3c specifications (ouch, that hurts my brain...) and a few wikipedia articles, I think I'll use a combination of jar and XInclude. I'll put the jar-archive-relative paths to the csv files in some xml attribute (I'll name it type) with the mimetype application/csv. Member data field objects of the main type that has to be serialized will be in their own xml file in the jar with a master file that will xinclude them.

Answer (score 2):

XML schema allows you to define a collection type where the items are separated by a space.

```
<xs:list itemType="xs:int"/>
```

Below is a full example of how you could leverage this in JAXB to represent a matrix.

**Java Model (Root)**

We will use a 2 dimensional int array to represent out matrix.  We will use an `XmlAdapter` to get a non-default array representation (see: [JAXB & java.util.Map](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html))

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private int[][] matrix;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MatrixAdapter.class)
    public int[][] getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    public void setMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

}
```

**XmlAdapter (MatrixAdapter)**

When you annotate `int[]` with `@XmlValue` the XML representation will be space separated text.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MatrixAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MatrixAdapter.AdaptedMatrix, int[][]>{

    public static class AdaptedMatrix {
        @XmlElement(name="row")
        public List<AdaptedRow> rows;
    }

    public static class AdaptedRow {

        @XmlValue
        public int[] row;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMatrix marshal(int[][] matrix) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMatrix adaptedMatrix = new AdaptedMatrix();
        adaptedMatrix.rows = new ArrayList<AdaptedRow>(matrix.length);
        for(int[] row : matrix) {
            AdaptedRow adaptedRow = new AdaptedRow();
            adaptedRow.row = row;
            adaptedMatrix.rows.add(adaptedRow);
        }
        return adaptedMatrix;
    }

    @Override
    public int[][] unmarshal(AdaptedMatrix adaptedMatrix) throws Exception {
        List<AdaptedRow> adaptedRows = adaptedMatrix.rows;
        int[][] matrix = new int[adaptedRows.size()][];
        for(int x=0; x<adaptedRows.size(); x++) {
            matrix[x] = adaptedRows.get(x).row;
        }
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

Below is some demo code you can run to prove that everything works:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17119708/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <matrix>
      <row>1 2 3 4</row>
      <row>5 6 7 8</row>
   </matrix>
</root>
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <matrix>
        <row>1 2 3</row>
        <row>4 5 6</row>
        <row>7 8 9</row>
    </matrix>
</root>
```

Comment: For simple arrays, it could be ok, but for a generic collection, you'd have to write 10 times more code.

Comment: ... and you can't import your xml file into excel.

Answer (score 1):

XML is a good format to structure some kind of information but a pain for others like matrix, beyond the technical limitations of the XML libraries, because you don't want to clutter your clean tabular representation with all these horrible angle brackets everywhere and you often want quick parsing based on split.

In this case you should avoid the "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" syndrome, you need another representation that can naturally handle tabular data: CSV.

So your idea of combining the strengths of both format is the right idea: XML for data that need structuring, CSV for tabular data.

As for the MIME type if only your application will be dealing with the file you really don't need to specify it but adding one really don't cost a lot; but I don't know if any standard attributes exists, except maybe something like "*xsi:type="CSV"*".

PS: I've written about the aforementioned syndrome in a different context: http://pragmateek.com/if-all-you-have-is-a-hammer/ :)